# How to install PowerShell module pushed to Azure Artifacts in Pipelines?

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-artifacts

Following [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/tutorials/private-powershell-library?view=azure-devops) I set up Pipelines to push a PowerShell module to my Artifacts feed.

I can install the module on my local machine, but I was wondering how I can do the same in Pipelines? It seems adding the NuGet source is an interactive process, so how can Pipelines add the Artifacts feed as a source?

The issue is that I don't want to have any user interaction in a CI environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using self-hosted agent, you need to configure the folder `module` permission, self-hosted agent run the cmd via service account instead of personal account.

If you are using hosted agent, add the task power shell and enter below script to install the module.

```
$patToken = "$(pat)" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force

$credsAzureDevopsServices = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential("xxx", $patToken)


Register-PSRepository -Name "PowershellAzureDevopsServices" -SourceLocation "https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/{Org name}/{project name}/_packaging/{feed name}/nuget/v2" -PublishLocation "https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/{Org name}/{project name}/_packaging/{feed name}/nuget/v2" -InstallationPolicy Trusted -Credential $credsAzureDevopsServices

Get-PSRepository

Find-Module -Repository PowershellAzureDevopsServices -Credential $credsAzureDevopsServices


Install-Module -Name Get-Hello -Repository PowershellAzureDevopsServices -Credential $credsAzureDevopsServices


Get-Module -ListAvailable Get-Hello
```

Result:

[image]

**Update1**

We need to enter the code during the registration of the power supply enclosure repository, the method is `Register-PSRepository`

This is a certification issue, If we change the authentication method, maybe we don’t need to enter the code.

In addition, We could also install the module via the cmd `Install-Module Get-Hello -Scope CurrentUser -Force`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I got this far actually, but this process of going to a browser and entering a code, how frequent will I have to do this? This carries a risk of a pipeline stalling because user input is required to continue.

Comment: Hi, I have updated the answer, please check the update1 and then kindly share the result here.

Comment: Hi @iTiamo, Just checking in to see whether this issue is still blocking you now? Any update for this issue?

Comment: I have found a solution to my problem in the following blogpost. In short: using PowerShellGet module version 3.0.0 (in beta right now) we can skip the device code flow and install PowerShell modules non-interactively.

 https://www.pipehow.tech/new-psrepository/#avoiding-the-device-code