# PowerShellGet "unable to find package source" upon Install-Module, despite Find-Module working correctly

Tags: powershell, azure-artifacts

I recently created an Azure Artifacts feed for one of the projects in my organization. I followed the [instructions at this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/tutorials/private-powershell-library?view=azure-devops#creating-packaging-and-sending-a-module).

Most things work. In particular, I'm able to:

- Create the feed
- Use `nuget` to push a package to said feed
- Register the feed with PowerShell via `Register-PSRepository`
- Run `Find-Module -Repository <Repository Name>`

The last bit -- running `Find-Module` -- generates the expected output, viz., a single module with the expected version, name, and description. However, I get the following message when I attempt `Install-Module`:

```
PS C:\Windows\System32> install-module -name ADHelpers -Repository 'ADHelpersTest2'
Install-Package: C:\Users\my_name\OneDrive\Documents\PowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\2.2.5\PSModule.psm1:9711
Line |
9711 |  … talledPackages = PackageManagement\Install-Package @PSBoundParameters
     |                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Unable to resolve package source
     | 'https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/my_organization/my_project/_packaging/my_feed/nuget/v2'.
```

I've scrubbed my organization, project, and feed name, as I don't think that's important for solving this problem.

My question is simple: What could cause this? I'm confused that I'm able to `Find-Module` just fine, but unable to run `Install-Module` for the result that `Find-Module` successfully fetches.

I've been unsuccessful in finding guidance elsewhere, and am unsure what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks in advance -- I appreciate your time.

Comment: Hi, How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: Hi, Just checking in to see whether this issue is still blocking you now? Any update for this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to install the custom package in the Azure DevOps pipeline, you could add task power shell and run the script `Install-Package ADHelpers -Scope CurrentUser -Force`
to install the package.

In my sample, the package name is Get-Hello and the result is:

[image]

You could refer to this [blog](https://www.pipehow.tech/new-psrepository/#avoiding-the-device-code) and my [previous answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65590221/13903626) for more details

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! I wasn't aware of how to install modules _during_ builds, so that was helpful.

What actually resolved this problem was the blog post. I hadn't tried using PowerShellGet v3.0.0. For reasons I still don't understand, that resolved my issue. 

Thanks so much for the help, this just made things a lot easier for a lot of people. Cheers :)